# How I can access DB2 using batch files(.bat)

Tags: batch-file, ibm-midrange, db2-400

Want a syntax where I can give my DB2 details like server name,user name,password and sql file which want to execute using batch file.
I found syntax like sqlplus,sqlcmd for oracle and sql server respectively but no luck for 'DB2'.
Pls help me in it.

**Note** that this is about DB2 on the IBM i platform (see comments).

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, from a command prompt, type `db2cmd`, then from there run e.g. `db2 connect to YOUR_DATABASE user YOUR_USER_ID` then e.g. `db2 -tf filename.sql`

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002036.html

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0010410.html

Comment: 'db2cmd' is not recognised an internal or external command,program or batch file.

Comment: Have you installed a Db2 client?

Comment: Yes we installed DB2 client

Comment: DB2 is hosted on IBM iSeries servers running a proprietary operating system called i7.1 This is entirely different to anything else on planet earth .  
The iSeries is fairly unique in so far as the DB2 version is the same as the operating system version. This is because DB2 is fully integrated into the iSeries operating system and it is not an optional product. At the moment, database are running IBM iSeries operating system at level v7.1 – so this is also the DB2 version/release We are working on Windows operating system

Comment: Which client have you installed? You need the IBM Data Server Client or the IBM Data Server Runtime Client to have the Db2 Command Line Processor (CLP) installed https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=ibm10720011    FYI the default install path is "C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER"   https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.install.doc/doc/t0007315.html?pos=2  and `db2cmd` and `db2` will be under that path

Answer (score 0):

IBM i Access Client Solutions (which I assume you have available to you, this part of its functionality being free of charge) has a command line option for this, e.g.

```
java -jar acsbundle.jar /SYSTEM=MYAS400 /PLUGIN=rss /file=\mysqlscript.sql /autorun=1
```

See ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/as400/products/clientaccess/solutions/GettingStarted_en.html for more information (specifically section 9.1.31).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Db2 Client installed & add following snippet in your batch file.

```
SET DB2CLP=DB20FADE

runas /noprofile /user:db2admin "db2cmd -c db2 create database MyDatabase && db2 connect to MyDatabase && db2 -tvmf db2_create_tables.sql"
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, I guess you didn't really search.

[Db2 has several command line interfaces](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc-gentopic1.html) that can be and are used for batch processing. Clpplus even offers Oracle-like syntax support and compatibility. There is even a tool named [db2batch](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002043.html) that allows to process statements with lots of options.

Comment: 'clplus' is not re-cognized an internal or external command,program or batch file.
Getting this message when running in command prompt

Comment: What version of DB2 or the Db2 client have you installed? On what OS? Did you follow the instructions?

Comment: DB2 is hosted on IBM iSeries servers running a proprietary operating system called i7.1
This is entirely different to anything else on planet earth 

Comment: The iSeries is fairly unique in so far as the DB2 version is the same as the operating system version.
This is because DB2 is fully integrated into the iSeries operating system and it is not an optional product.

At the moment, database are running IBM iSeries operating system at level v7.1 – so this is also the DB2 version/release
We are working on Windows operating system.